# App Store - App publishing rejected other as reason?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I want to publish my first IOS app in App Store, for the first time, and the reason for rejection is "Other", what is that "Other" what does that mean?

```
iOS App 1.0 | App Version
Rejection Reasons:
Other
```

Is necessary to put iPad screenshots? (That fields are empty right now)

0 of 3 App Previews <- What does this mean?

Please help!

Comment: Any news? I still got the same rejected reasons...